# Why showing Null Pointer Exception While using JFrame in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, jframe

Error******************************************************************

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Code********************************************************************

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame w = new JFrame();
        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        slider.setMinimum(1023);
        w.add(slider);
        w.pack();
        w.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you're running? Works fine on my machine.

Comment: The answers in that other question are very helpful in case of a `NullPointerException` in one’s own code. This exception comes from deep within AWT behind a call to a Swing constructor, so it’s different. @Japu_D_Cret

Comment: what is your Runtime Environment? exact Java Version and Manufacturer? (e.g. OpenJDK 1.8.0_121)

Comment: I downloaded and installed New JDK. Does eclipse can access this ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Jonathan Sterling, Japu_D_Cret and chetan mehra. It worked well. I downloaded the exact version of Eclipse (Luna) prescribed in that video [ youtu.be/8B6j_yr9H8g ] and new JDK, Nothing else. The problem was with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

you hadnt add setbounds(); in your java code try w.setbounds(100,100,200,200);.Usually null pointer exception came when the reference of an object is null.Try this .Hope it will work for you.

Comment: What is setbounds();

Comment: How can I add setbounds();  to my program ?

Comment: it's a method of `java.awt.Component` from which your JFrame and your JSlider inherit - you can call it on your JFrame with `w.setBounds(int, int, int, int)` but this will most certainly not fix your problem since your error occurs in the initialization of the JFrame in the first line, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html for reference

Comment: Actually I found this code form YouTube , https://youtu.be/8B6j_yr9H8g , And not working on My computer

Comment: which ide are you using?

Comment: Since you are using a public class so name of the class and name of program must be same with.java extension.I run this code and it works fine in my machine

Comment: I cannot believe this answer answers the question. I see no connection to the stacktrace reported. Also `w.pack()` should set a suitable window size.

Comment: IDE I am using : eclipse for android development.